# Is there a way to step over dotnet source in LLDB on macOS

Tags: macos, .net-core, lldb

I'm investigating how to debug .NET apps on macOS. So far I have successfully compiled LLDB 3.9 with libsosplugin.dylib and have learned how to open the application in it. However, I could not find a way to list source and put breakpoint in it.

```
$HOME/SDK/build/release/bin/lldb-3.9.1 \
  -o "plugin load $HOME/SDK/coreclr/bin/Product/OSX.x64.Debug/libsosplugin.dylib" \
  -o "process launch -s" \
  dotnet ./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.2/app.dll
```

When I stop the app with Crtl+C and type `l` for sources, it just does nothing.

```
Process 39465 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x979f6, 0x0000000102b85795 libcoreclr.dylib`WKS::gc_heap::mark_object_simple(unsigned char**) + 293, stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
    frame #0: 0x0000000102b85795 libcoreclr.dylib`WKS::gc_heap::mark_object_simple(unsigned char**) + 293
libcoreclr.dylib`WKS::gc_heap::mark_object_simple:
->  0x102b85795 <+293>: movq   %rax, %rcx
    0x102b85798 <+296>: orq    $0x1, %rcx
    0x102b8579c <+300>: movq   %rcx, (%rdi)
    0x102b8579f <+303>: testb  $0x1, %al
(lldb) l
(lldb)
```

Is it ever possible to see dotnet app sources in LLDB?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like there is any debug information for that function - certainly not any lldb can find or read. Without that, lldb won't be able to construct the map from PC -> source location and so no source based operations are going to work.

lldb only supports the DWARF and PDB debug formats (and PDB is a work in progress and was not present in lldb-3.9.1 which is a pretty old lldb.)

I have not played around with compiling .NET apps on macOS, so I don't know what options it offers for debug information.  You'll need to figure out that first.